# Keyboard and mouse stuttering on Ubuntu 18.04 with a new laptop

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

On my LG Gram 17" (i7 8-th generation), I've got the problem in ubuntu.
Keyboard and mouse sometimes are starting to stutter, repeat once pressed keys and lag.

Did someone else face this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the workaround so far - setting the poll rate for keyboard and mouse to 1000 Hz (originally written he 125Hz by mistake):

```
sudo su
echo 1 > /sys/module/usbhid/parameters/kbpoll
echo 1 > /sys/module/usbhid/parameters/mousepoll
```

and replugged the usb hub.

As a permanent solution - these two parameters `usbhid.kbpoll=1 usbhid.mousepoll=1` should be added to the end of the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable in the `/etc/default/grub` file.
So the variable should be looking like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbhid.kbpoll=1 usbhid.mousepoll=1"
```

...and perform the:

```
update-grub
```

Comment: This appears to have fixed my mouse and keyboard stuttering problem on Archlinux (Manjaro). Thank you very much for providing the solution.

Comment: Note that a polling rate of 1 is 1000Hz, not 125Hz.

Comment: As a security precaustion, remember to exit `su`

Comment: For those looking for more info on setting polling values, it's rate = 1000 / interval. Therefore 8 would be 125HZ.

Comment: @jshook so 0 is infinite (or undefined)? (my value is 0 - and it only stutters  during high cpu usage)